# List non zero elements from sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

How to list, in a simple and one line code (and fast!), all non zero elements of a `csr_matrix`?

I'm using this code:

```
edges_list = list([tuple(row) for row in np.transpose(A.nonzero())])
weight_list = [A[e] for e in edges_list]
```

but it is taking quite a long time to execute.

Answer (score 5):

For a CSR matrix in canonical form, access the data array directly:

```
A.data
```

but be aware that matrices not in canonical form may include explicit zeros or duplicate entries in their representation, which will need special handling. For example,

```
# Merge duplicates and remove explicit zeros. Both operations modify A.
# We sum duplicates first because they might sum to zero - for example,
# if a 5 and a -5 are in the same spot, we have to sum them to 0 and then remove the 0.
A.sum_duplicates()
A.eliminate_zeros()

# Now use A.data
do_whatever_with(A.data)
```

Comment: How do I know if they are in canonical form?

Comment: @Miguel: Usually, because of guarantees provided by the data source. For example, if you created the matrix yourself, you might know that you created it in a way that can't produce explicit zeros or duplicate entries.

Comment: Ok I'm int that scenario where I create it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `A.nonzero()` to index into `A` directly:

```
In [19]: A = np.random.randint(0, 3, (3, 3))

In [20]: A
Out[20]: 
array([[2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [21]: A[A.nonzero()]
Out[21]: array([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1])
```

The result is the same as with your approach:

```
In [22]: edges_list = list([tuple(row) for row in np.transpose(A.nonzero())])

In [23]: [A[e] for e in edges_list]
Out[23]: [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

And obviously quite a bit faster (and more so if the matrix gets bigger):

```
In [25]: %timeit [A[e] for e in list([tuple(row) for row in np.transpose(A.nonzero())])]
10000 loops, best of 3: 48 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit A[A.nonzero()]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop
```

Also works with `scipy` `csr_matrix`, although there are better methods for those, as shown in other answers:

```
In [30]: M = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)

In [31]: M[M.nonzero()]
Out[31]: matrix([[2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: That's a regular NumPy array, not a SciPy CSR matrix.

Comment: @user2357112 To be honest, I wasn't aware the question is specific to scipy. But shouldn't this still work, and also be more generally applicable?

Comment: It still works, but the array tests are misleading. The output type and structure are different with a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` - see how the result is a `numpy.matrix` rather than an ndarray. Also, the performance characteristics of sparse matrix indexing are very different from regular array indexing.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing out, as I said, I wasn't aware of that. I'll still leave this here, as the question is not explicitly titled or tagged as `scipy` and others may still find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `A.data`

```
In [16]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [17]: A = csr_matrix([[1,0,0],[0,2,0]])

In [18]: A.data
Out[18]: array([1, 2])
```

If the sparse matrix has been modified or to be safe, you should use: `A.eliminate_zeros()`

```
In [19]: A[0,0] = 0

In [20]: A.data
Out[20]: array([0, 2])

In [21]: A.eliminate_zeros()

In [22]: A.data
Out[22]: array([2])
```

Comment: This could return zero elements-- try`A[0,0] = 0` before `A.data`.  You'd need to add `A.eliminate_zeros()` first, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scipy.sparse.find` like this:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, find
>>> A = csr_matrix([[7.0, 8.0, 0],[0, 0, 9.0]])
>>> find(A)
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2], 
dtype=int32), array([ 7.,  8.,  9.]))
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html